# Measure algebra homomorphisms and isomorphisms: what are they?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Are there established notions of when two measure algebras are isomorphic?
More generally, what is a (standard definition of) homomorphism of measure algebras?

A reference would be welcome.